# Elasticsearch Transportclient throws a NoNodeAvailableException in an integration test

Tags: java, elasticsearch

So I've a test where I try to connect to a local embedded Elasticsearch node that usually works with other tests. The embedded node is also local = true. It works in two other tests, one uses the HTTP Rest API and the other the data less node client. They both work good.

But when I try to use the TransportClient like this:

```
  Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", false)
                .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
                .put("client.transport.sniff", false)
                .put("client.transport.ping_timeout", pingTimeout)
                .put("client.transport.nodes_sampler_interval", pingSamplerInterval).build();

        client = new TransportClient(settings);

        String hostPieces[] = hosts.split(",");
        for (String piece : hostPieces){
            String hostAndPort[] = piece.trim().split(":");
            if (hostAndPort.length != 2){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error in hosts string: "+ piece);
            }
            String host = hostAndPort[0].trim();
            String portStr = hostAndPort[1].trim();

            InetSocketTransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(host, Integer.valueOf(portStr));

            client.addTransportAddress(address);
        }
```

although at the begging it seems to connect to the local node, then it dies:

```
[2014-04-01 15:31:21,504][DEBUG][org.elasticsearch.client.transport] [Googam] adding address [[#transport#-1][d][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:11547]]]
[2014-04-01 15:31:21,517][DEBUG][org.elasticsearch.transport.netty] [Googam] connected to node [[#transport#-1][d][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:11547]]]
[2014-04-01 15:31:31,316][DEBUG][org.elasticsearch.cluster.service] [Sepulchre] processing [routing-table-updater]: execute
[2014-04-01 15:31:31,317][DEBUG][org.elasticsearch.cluster.service] [Sepulchre] processing [routing-table-updater]: no change in cluster_state
[2014-04-01 15:32:16,521][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.client.transport] [Googam] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][d][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:11547]], disconnecting...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:11547]][cluster/nodes/info] request_id [0] timed out after [55001ms]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:356)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[2014-04-01 15:32:16,525][DEBUG][org.elasticsearch.transport.netty] [Googam] disconnected from [[#transport#-1][d][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:11547]]]
[2014-04-01 15:32:16,527][DEBUG][org.elasticsearch.transport.netty] [Googam] connected to node [[#transport#-1][d][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:11547]]]
[2014-04-01 15:32:16,530][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Sepulchre] stopping ...
[2014-04-01 15:32:16,530][DEBUG][org.elasticsearch.transport.netty] [Googam] disconnected from [[#transport#-1][d][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:11547]]], channel closed event
[2014-04-01 15:32:16,532][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.client.transport] [Googam] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][d][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:11547]], disconnecting...
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:11547]][cluster/nodes/info] disconnected
[2014-04-01 15:32:16,534][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Sepulchre] stopped
Exception in thread "Thread-1" org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
```

In the log you have Googam that is the TransportClient and Sepulchre that is the embedded node.

Comment: have you configured ES TCP port manually???

Comment: Yes, I did on the embedded node. It works fine in other tests.

Comment: Transport client creation takes some time.. Pls try increasing client.transport.ping_timeout value..!

Comment: I put it to 50s... same result :(